# How can I save parsed xml as txt?

Tags: python, urllib

I have parsed XML to list, and I'd like to save this as txt file.

But there's an error..

How can I save it to txt..?

I am a very starter of python, so I don't know how to do.

My xml url is https://pvxml.map.naver.com/api/get?type=xml&pano_id=/c7VUP7/zsr2UT/De2VlQA==&rv=3

And I would like to parse the street_panorama id.

```
import os
import urllib.request as urllib from xml.dom
import minidom
with open ('list.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('C:/Users/JYLEE/Desktop/python/exercise')
    url = 'https://pvxml.map.naver.com/api/get?type=xml&pano_id=/c7VUP7/zsr2UT/De2VlQA==&rv=3' 
    dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
    link = dom.getElementsByTagName('street_panorama')
    categories = [items.attributes['id'].value for items in link if items.attributes['id']]
    f.write(categories)
```

The error message is `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`

I don't know what to do next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert the list (`categories`) into a string format by using the `str()` method.

Also, try to use `with` statements whenever you are trying to `read` or `write` a file. If you use `read` or `write` commands barely you should close the file after the usage using `f.close()` command.

This is taken care automatically if you use `with` command.

This is the corrected code of yours for your reference

```
import os
import urllib.request as urllib 
from xml.dom import minidom
with open("list1.txt",'w') as f:
    f.write('C:/Users/JYLEE/Desktop/python/exercise')

url = 'https://pvxml.map.naver.com/api/get?type=xml&pano_id=/c7VUP7/zsr2UT/De2VlQA==&rv=3' 
dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
link = dom.getElementsByTagName('street_panorama')
categories = [items.attributes['id'].value for items in link if items.attributes['id']]
with open("list1.txt",'w') as f:
    f.write(str(categories))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, it requires passing a string. You could simply do `write(str(categories))` to get a representation similar to `['a', 'b', 'c']` or `[1, 2, 3]`. If you want each on a new line, or some specific format, loop over `categories` and write to the file item by item.